# Flash fallback not working in case HTML video is not supported

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am using HTML video with flash fallback on my [site](http://toda.net) but the flash doesnt seem to work in case HTML video is not supported. Do I need to include any javascript file to make this work ?

```
<video width="800" height="400" preload="" 
    onloadeddata="document.getElementById('videoLoadImg').style.display = 'none';"    
    poster="/admin/config/header_files/top.jpg" autoplay="">

    <source src="/admin/config/header_files/top.mp4" type='video/mp4;' />
    <source src="/admin/config/header_files/top.webm" type='video/webm; 
        codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
    <source src="/admin/config/header_files/top.ogv" type='video/ogg; 
        codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
    <embed src='/admin/config/header_files/top.swf' 
        type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='800' height='400'
        allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='false'></embed>
    <img src='/admin/config/header_files/cake.jpg' />
</video>
```

The HTML video is not working on my iMac with Safari 5.0.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be the video is not auto played? because when I open WebKit Inspector and try

```
document.querySelector('video').play()
```

and it works. This case you could the code above to jQuery DOMReady, or add the `autoplay` attribute like this:

```
<video autobuffer autoplay>
```

FYI: I have Safari 5.1.2, however I believe Safari has support for HTML5 video around 4.0.

Comment: didn't it worked on its own on your computer as well? and regarding the autobuffer i heard when  autobuffer & autoplay are both placed then autobuffer is anyways ingnored..?

Comment: autoplay is already there incase the platform is not ipad / iphone or ipod

Comment: @Marcos I see. For me the video is not downloaded. Everything starts working when I do the `.play()`.

Comment: thanks, could you let me know what should be the fix. I want to autoplay the video once it is completely loaded.. i was trusting simply `autoplay` for this .. i dont want it to play unless its fully loaded.. should i do something like `onloadeddata='$(this).play();'` ?

Comment: i have added `onloadeddata='$(this).play();'`  now to the video element on this test link(http://www.toda.net/test1.php), could you please test this now on your browser and see if it works *now on its own* after loaded? thanks so much for you help...

Comment: OK, because I am also struggling with this problem so I download the files and try to reproduce the problem locally. It looks like the `poster` attribute is buggy. Remove it or invoke the video play manually in `DOMReady`

Let see if it works for you too.

Comment: @Marcos: So `$(this).play()` works for you? I think at least it should be `$('video-js-box video').get(0).play()`

Comment: actually i m not able to reproduce the problem right now found it while testing on my friend's imac. I am  manually trying to play the files when the video is loaded by using `onloadeddata='this.play();'`.. actually cant remove the poster attribute..

Comment: yes previosly i was wrong using: $(this).play(); **<- this is wrong**. I have rectitfied it now, you can try testing now on this link (http://www.toda.net/test1.php)